# Keycloak console links broken when running behind proxy

Tags: keycloak

I have keycloak admin UI working behind nginx at a non-root path like /keycloak. However some things still don't work, which make me wonder if I got everything covered. I'm running v11.0.2 standalone.

First I followed the guidance in the docs:

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_setting-up-a-load-balancer-or-proxy

then I still had to update the frontendUrl property in the spi section of standalone.xml.

When I log in as a user to the realm in the console, then click the sign out link in the upper right it just goes straight to /auth, not keycloak/auth because the sign out link has the wrong redirect_uri. Where is that configured ?

Same issue if I'm in admin and I click the Keycloak logo in the nav. This url looks correct but it redirects to /auth again. This is the logo image link url:

https://myhost/keycloak/auth/admin/master/console/#

which then redirects to:

https://myhost/auth/

which is a 404. If these are just things that were missed in the admin app then not really a big deal, but I want to make sure I didn't miss something in the config for the proxy setup. The endpoints look correct at:

myhost/keycloak/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration